# Cannot covert String Array to Int32

Tags: c#

**My Code**:

```
basketsub.Properties.ColorId = Convert.ToInt32(itemspliters[3] != null 
  ? itemspliters[3].ToString() 
  : "0");
```

**Error**:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object!!!

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Have you debugged the code in your IDE of choice to determine which of the many members in that line of code is null?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [mcve].

Comment: Check `itemspliters`, `basketsub`, `basketsub.Properties` is any of them `null`?

Comment: This code will through an NRE if the array itself is empty. You should ensure the values *aren't* empty to begin with, instead of trying to handle nulls. The code needs quite a bit of cleaning too. If `itemspliters` contains strings, `ToString()` isn't needed. If not, what *does* it contain?

Comment: In any case you can use the null propagation operator to safely get the value and not even attempt to convert if there's a problem, eg `var value=itemspliters?[3]?.ToString(); basketsub.Properties.ColorId=(value==null)?0:int.Parse(value);`

Answer (score 0):

You  should also check itemspliters != null

```
basketsub.Properties.ColorId = Convert.ToInt32(itemspliters != null && itemspliters.Length >= 4 && itemspliters[3] != null 
  ? itemspliters[3].ToString() 
  : "0");
```